# How to print a periodic number WITHOUT rounding up to n decimals?

Tags: c++, c, printing

Let's say x = 2/3 and n = 10

then I would like to print:
.6666666666   (10 sixes, because n is 10)

instead of
.6666666667   <- I don't want that seven!!!!

How would you print in that way either in C or C++ ?

Comment: post your code and see this [How do I ask homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812)

Comment: It's not a homework question...

Comment: then where is your code

Comment: I got this rare formatting problem from here: http://coj.uci.cu/24h/problem.xhtml?abb=1497

Comment: I hope you agree that the formatting is not the core problem.

Comment: See i am  just suggesting you , if you post question like this most of the people will consider this  as some assignment / homework. if you post with code that shows your effort and you will get better answers than you expect And formatting is linked with code. if you use %f it will produce 6 fractional digits and %.2f will produce 2 fractional digits. different usages will give different results. at least if we Know which format you are using we might suggest some alternative.

Comment: Weird. 0.667 is a better approximation than 0.666, it's off by 0.0003333... (1/3000) instead of 0.0006666.... (2/3000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:

```
double foo = 2.0 / 3.0;
printf("%.10f", floor(foo * pow(10, 10)) / pow(10, 10));
```

C++:

```
double foo = 2.0 / 3.0;
std::cout
    << std::fixed
    << std::setprecision(10)
    << std::floor(foo * std::pow(10.0, 10.0)) / std::pow(10.0, 10.0);
```

Comment: @LayGonzález Yay. And for floor, `#include <cmath>`. But that can be easily found by googling anyway.

Comment: I have same issue using C++. I used the solution and it is still rounding it seems. The value I have is unique, 2.88496. I want it to display 2.884, however the 9 rounds up to 5, and adding another precision rounds the 9 to 10 which makes the 4 a 5 as well. Any solution for a value like this?